# How to tell eslint that you prefer single quotes around your strings

Tags: node.js, eslint

I'm new to eslint and it's spewing out a ton of errors telling me to use doublequotes:

```
error  Strings must use doublequote
```

That's not my preference.  I've got an .eslintrc file set up with the basics:

```
{
  "env": {
    "node": 1
  }
}
```

I'd like to configure it for single quotes.

Answer (score 137):

http://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes.html

```
{
  "env": {
    "node": 1
  },
  "rules": {
    "quotes": [2, "single", { "avoidEscape": true }]
  }
}
```

Comment: If I need to use either of single or double quotes, what to change in above rule ?

Comment: @Antonius Bloch, this solution doesn't work in my Vue.js project...

`"eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "no-console": "off",
      "quotes": [1, "single", { "avoidEscape": true }]
 },`

Comment: What is the `2` for? I can't see any explanation in that link.

Comment: @ryan2johnson9 It is a rule severity level: 0 = off, 1 = warn, 2 = error

Answer (score 57):

If you're using TypeScript/ES6 you might want to include template literals (backticks).  This rule prefers single quotes, and allows template literals.

**TypeScript Examples**

```json
"@typescript-eslint/quotes": [
  "error",
  "single",
  {
    "allowTemplateLiterals": true
  }
]
```

Another useful option is to allow single or double quotes as long as the string contains an escapable quote like `"lorem ipsum 'donor' eta"` or `'lorem ipsum "donor" eta'`.

```json
"@typescript-eslint/quotes": [
  "error",
  "single",
  {
    "avoidEscape": true,
    "allowTemplateLiterals": true
  }
]
```

References:

**ESLint**

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes

**TypeScript ESLint**

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/quotes.md

Comment: I don't think you need to set `allowTemplateLiterals` to `true` unless you want to allow using template literal strings even when only single quotes would work. Template literals are allowed by default. This can easily be tested.

Comment: both examples in the post are exactly the same showing example for `allowTemplateLiterals`, very confusing. Downvoting until fixed.

Comment: @oyalhi yep somehow missed `avoidEscape`.  Thanks

Answer (score 26):

```
rules: {
  'prettier/prettier': [
    'warn',
    {
      singleQuote: true,
      semi: true,
    }
  ],
},
```

In version `"eslint": "^7.21.0"`

Comment: Could you please add more info on why it becomes possible?

Comment: ...and why it is necessary (= why eslint fixer from @typescript-eslint package won't suffice)

Answer (score 5):

For jsx strings, if you would like to set this rule for all files, create the rule in the eslint config file.

```
  rules: {
    'jsx-quotes': [2, 'prefer-single'],
  }
```

Or 'prefer-double' for double quotes.

Answer (score 4):

If you also want to allow double quotes if they would avoid escaping a single quote inside the string, and allow template literals (the reasonable defaults, imo) try the following:

```
{
  "env": {
    "node": 1
  },
  "rules": {
    "quotes": [2, "single", { "avoidEscape": true, "allowTemplateLiterals": true }]
  }
}
```